# Send string as a file using curl and php

Tags: php, post, curl

I know I can use this syntaxt to send a file using php, post and curl.

```
$post = array(
    "file_box"=>"@/path/to/myfile.jpg",
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

How can I take a string, build a temp file and send it using the exact same syntax ?

Update:
I would prefer using tmpfile() or php://memory so I don't have to handle file creation.

Comment: duplicate of this question: [POST a file string using cURL in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085990/post-a-file-string-using-curl-in-php) (you will find your answer there)

Comment: Not a real answer there. @emil gave a great solution so far.

Comment: Erm, yes it is a real answer to send a file through curl when you have its content in a string. Tatu's answer is a different solution that involves temporary files (so you're not sending a string as file, you are sending an actual file).

Comment: @johnlemon: You asked too early, the answer is here: [PHP create random tmp file and get its full path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16487099/367456) - at least for the  tmpfile() part and how to create one from string and obtain the path to it then so you can use it in the (now defunct) @ syntax.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a file using [tempnam](http://php.net/tempnam) in your temp directory:

```
$string = 'random string';

//Save string into temp file
$file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'POST');
file_put_contents($file, $string);

//Post file
$post = array(
    "file_box"=>'@'.$file,
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

//do your cURL work here...

//Remove the file
unlink($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 8.1 there's also [`CURLStringFile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlstringfile.php) which would allow you to send it without the temporary file:

```php
$txt = 'test content';
$file = new \CURLStringFile($txt, 'filename.txt', 'text/plain');

$ch = curl_init('https://example.com/upload');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['file' => $file]);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Technically not the @ syntax op asks about. Why not consider to move the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3085990/367456 ? It looks like a better fit for this reference to me. (you can ping me there so that I can move my +1 there, too).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary file using `file_put_contents`, just make sure that the target directory is writable.

```
$path = '/path/to/myfile.txt';    
file_put_contents($myData, $path);

$post = array(
    "file_box"=>"@".$path,
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

# Delete the file if you don't need it anymore
unlink($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php#115161

> ```
> $files = array()) {
>   
>              // invalid characters for "name" and "filename"
>              static $disallow = array("\0", "\"", "\r", "\n");
>
>              // build normal parameters
>              foreach ($assoc as $k => $v) {
>                  $k = str_replace($disallow, "_", $k);
>                  $body[] = implode("\r\n", array(
>                      "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$k}\"",
>                      "",
>                      filter_var($v),
>                  ));
>              }
>
>              // build file parameters
>              foreach ($files as $k => $v) {
>                  switch (true) {
>                      case false === $v = realpath(filter_var($v)):
>                      case !is_file($v):
>                      case !is_readable($v):
>                          continue; // or return false, throw new InvalidArgumentException
>                  }
>                  $data = file_get_contents($v);
>                  $v = call_user_func("end", explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $v));
>                  $k = str_replace($disallow, "_", $k);
>                  $v = str_replace($disallow, "_", $v);
>                  $body[] = implode("\r\n", array(
>                      "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$k}\"; filename=\"{$v}\"",
>                      "Content-Type: image/jpeg",
>                      "",
>                      $data,
>                  ));
>              }
>
>              // generate safe boundary
>              do {
>                  $boundary = "---------------------" . md5(mt_rand() . microtime());
>              } while (preg_grep("/{$boundary}/", $body));
>
>              // add boundary for each parameters
>              array_walk($body, function (&$part) use ($boundary) {
>                  $part = "--{$boundary}\r\n{$part}";
>              });
>
>              // add final boundary
>              $body[] = "--{$boundary}--";
>              $body[] = "";
>
>              // set options
>              return @curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
>                  CURLOPT_POST       => true,
>                  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => implode("\r\n", $body),
>                  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
>                      "Expect: 100-continue",
>                      "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary={$boundary}", // change Content-Type
>                  ),
>              ));
>          }
>
> $array1=array('other_post_field'=>'value');
> $array2=array('file'=>'document_content_string'); $ch = curl_init();  
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
> curl_custom_postfields($ch,$array1,$array2);//above custom function
> $output=curl_exec($ch); close($ch);
> ```