# PHP create random tmp file and get its full path

Tags: php, file, file-io, path

After I do:

```
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, "writing to tempfile");
```

I'd like to get a full path to the `$temp` file that `tmpfile` has created.

What do I need to do to get that information?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'prefix');
```

See [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php).

Comment: In the original code the file is removed when the script exits/crashes. This one leaves garbage behind. See @bishop's answer for the proper solution.

Comment: The first parameter for directory is not taken into consideration on Windows platfors. Which always uses C:\Windows\Temp\.

Answer (score 79):

[`tmpfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) returns a stream-able file pointer.

To get the corresponding path, [ask the stream for its meta data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php):

```
$file = tmpfile();
$path = stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri']; // eg: /tmp/phpFx0513a
```

The benefit of the `tmpfile` approach? PHP automatically removes the `$path` when `$file` goes out of scope. With `tempnam`, you must manually remove the created file.