# PHP download unique file

Tags: php, xml, file, gpx

I am trying to create an GPX file with coordinates that will then be downloaded by the user. The first part creates the file(which is working). But I can't seem to get it to download. I want this file created on the fly and downloaded so that when multiple users are using the service, their files can never interchange.

I think I should put my data in a variable instead of in a file but this way I could test if it was working.

I am new to coding, bound to make mistakes ;)

Thank you all in advance.

Here is what I have so far;

```
<?php
// set_include_path("http://localhost/The%20Road%20Planner/tempMap/");
// $filename = uniqid('route.') . '.gpx';

$myfile = fopen('route.gpx', 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");


$route = (isset($_POST['RoutePath']) ? $_POST['RoutePath'] : null);


fwrite($myfile, '<?xml version="1.0" ?>' . '<gpx version="1.0" creator="Fabrication Junkies" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd">' . PHP_EOL . '<trk>' . PHP_EOL .
 '<name>Map</name>' . PHP_EOL . '<trkseg>'.PHP_EOL);

$coordinates = json_decode($route, true);


foreach($coordinates as $pair) {
  $output = '<trkpt lat="' . $pair['lat'] .'" lon="'. $pair['lng'] . '"></trkpt>' . PHP_EOL;
  fwrite($myfile, $output);
}

fwrite($myfile, '</trkseg>' . PHP_EOL . '</trk>' . PHP_EOL . '</gpx>');
fclose($myfile);

 header("Content-type: application/gpx+xml");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=route.gpx");

 echo "<xml>";
// your gpx data here
$myfile
 echo "</xml>";
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487099/php-create-random-tmp-file-and-get-its-full-path

Comment: The problem with that is that it will save the file on the server and files can get mixed up, and take up space. I would like to be able to generate it and send it to the user. Not having to save the file on the server. In my example I write the file because it allows for the testing of the writing part of my script.

Comment: So don't create a file, don't write to a file, just output to the stdout. Instead of each fwrite($myfile,X), just print(X)

Comment: if you are creating a file and you are worried about multiple users downloading give it a name based on the user id, so each user has a unique file name.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create files in same directory and you don't want to mix the names you can use `uniqid()` function to make unique file names, like this

```
// preparing unique file name with time prefix
$prefix = uniqid(); // generates a uniqueId based on the microtime
$filePath = $prefix . "_route.gpx";

// opening and writing data inside
$myfile = fopen($filePath, 'w');
... fwrite() what you need inside
fclose($myfile);

// out as download
header("Content-type: application/gpx+xml");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=route.gpx");

readfile($filePath);
```

you can read more about `php` `uniqid()` here - http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_uniqid.asp

Answer (score 0):

You must create different names for your files. You can add SESSION_ID to filename:

```
<?php
$filename = session_id().'route.gpx';
$myfile = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");
?>
```

If users are logged you can add user id to the filename:

```
<?php
$filename = $user_id.'route.gpx';
?>
```