# PHP - create CSV file from POST $data = curl_exec($ch); that Contains only 1 big String

Tags: php, csv, curl, post, fputcsv

I did `$data = curl_exec($ch);` with POST method.
When I did echo `'<pre>',var_dump($data),'</pre>';`

```
string(15124) ""A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"
,"2",,"4","5",,,"8"
"ONE",,,"QW AH",,"US",,"EU""
```

I tried to split them and make into array `$lines = str_getcsv($data, PHP_EOL);`
But I got only 1 array with everything in it
`echo '<pre>',var_dump($lines),'</pre>';`

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(15121) ""A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"
,"2",,"4","5",,,"8"
"ONE",,,"QW AH",,"US",,"EU""
```

I want to create a csv file from that. So I did

```
$fp = fopen('../myfile.csv','w');
    fputcsv($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
```

I got the file, but when opened in excel the columns are not right.
How to actually split them row by row?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your data are already a csv. In short you have nothing to do except to save it to a file with `file_put_contents`.

About your approach:
You obtain only one item in your array because:

- `str_getcsv` is designed to read only one line of csv, not a whole csv string with multiple lines.
- the second parameter of `str_getcsv` is not the line separator (see the manual) but the item separator that isn't a newline.

But if you want to change how the csv looks like (the delimiter, the protection or escape character, the newline sequence), you have to read it and to write it line by line. A simple way to do that is to use `fopen()` with the [`data://` wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php), for example, to obtain a resource from a simple string. This way you don't have to split your data by lines since [`fgetcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) does it for you:

```
$data = '"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"
,"2",,"4","5",,,"8"
"ONE",,,"QW AH",,"US",,"EU"';
    
$fhi = fopen('data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($data), 'r');

if (false !== $fho = fopen('output.csv', 'w')) {
    while (false !== $row = fgetcsv($fhi)) {
        fputcsv($fho, $row, ';', '"', '\\', "\n"); // choose the parameters
    }
    
    close($fho);
}

close($fhi);
```

Comment: This is what I needed `file_put_contents` and thank you very much for bonus knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems some Microsof Excel versions tend to use semicolon ';' instead of comma ',' as seen at (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-keeps-on-using-semicolon-instead-of-comma/543510d9-65a8-4a0d-8464-a08fc0ac1c4f). It also may depend on locale and user settings.

In such case, changes from ',' to ';' may be needed according to user request.

E.g., for the data below...

```
// obtained data
$data = '"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"
,"2",,"4","5",,,"8"
"ONE",,,"QW AH",,"US",,"EU"';

// break it into lines
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);

// haven for the formatted rows
$csv_rows = [];

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // Breaks each line into cells by the comma,
    // ignoring eventual commas inside values
    $cells = preg_split('/,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)/', $line);

    // joins cells with semicolon
    $csv_rows[] = implode(';', $cells);
}

// result
$csv_text = implode(PHP_EOL, $csv_rows);
```

Result text:

```
"A";"B";"C";"D";"E";"F";"G";"H"
;"2";;"4";"5";;;"8" "ONE";;;"QW
AH";;"US";;"EU"
```

Tested within PHP Sandbox
→ https://onlinephp.io/c/23cc3

Improvements are welcome.

Comment: `file_put_contents` is actually the one I needed (I did not know this function before). But your answer also give me new knowledge of converting ',' I will surely need this for many other things. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1):

Just for my own reminder or anyone interested. This is what I do to finally get the file that I wanted.
Remove

```
$fp = fopen('../myfile.csv','w');
    fputcsv($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
```

and change to `file_put_contents('../myfile.csv','w');`

Thank you very much guys for explaining me that and showing even more bonus knowledge :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).