# send file data using PHP HttpRequest

Tags: php, httprequest

I have data that is contained within a variable (which can be written as a file), but I am looking to send it to a different server using PHP `HttpRequest`.

I thought of using `addRawPostData` but I it is deprecated now and I would prefer not to write the file to the client server then try and send it. If anyone has any ideas let me know. I also attempted to submit the raw data from the variable in a field in a normal `post` but it seems to be corrupted.

The file I am attempting to send is a torrent file, if this makes any difference.

Thanks again

Comment: [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) this is a simple example of a HTTP POST :

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.site.com/url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"key=value&key1=value1");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// Check response
if ($server_output == "OK") {
```

There is an example of POSTing a file string using cURL in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3086357/572939)

Answer (score 1):

To send a file using HttpRequest: http://www.php.net/manual/en/httprequest.addpostfile.php
To add raw post data: http://www.php.net/manual/en/httprequest.addrawpostdata.php - `HttpRequest::addRawPostData` is not deprecated, while `HttpRequest::setRawPostData` is deprecated.

However, HttpRequest is only a wrapper to [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and, in some cases, it would be better to use `cURL` directly.

Answer (score 0):

use setBody to send rawpost data http://www.php.net/manual/en/httprequest.setbody.php