# PHP curl upload from image create functions

Tags: php, image, post, curl, multipart

How can i upload an image using curl through image create functions (imgpng, imagecreatefromstring,..)

This is how i'm currently doing it normally without create functions

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post = array(
  "Filedata"=>"@{$file_location}"
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

how to do the same thing with an image function, lets say `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image_link));`

  and link it with the curl **without having to save the file**, directly through the function

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
imageceratefromstring($data);
```

Comment: Care to add some comments to your code and explain how it answers OP question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085990/post-a-file-string-using-curl-in-php). Note that in code you can avoid any encodging and just use it like:

```
$postFields['my_image'] = someFunctionForCreatingImage();
```