# Is it possible to use cURL to stream upload a file using POST?

Tags: php, curl

Or does PHP not allow this? I have read it is possible using PUT but the server is expecting POST only.

Comment: I believe that [pecl_http](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) is capable of doing something to that extent in the 2.x branch.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085990/post-a-file-string-using-curl-in-php

Comment: The server need to accept this with the content type application/octet-stream.

Answer (score 7):

cURL has already support for streams, try `curl --help | grep binary` and you will get:

> --data-binary DATA  HTTP POST binary data (H)

An example:

> curl -v -XPOST http://example:port/path --data-binary @file.tar 
> -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"

Comment: The @file will load the content in memory. Bad for big file. Use the -T option instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to *stream upload* a file using POST file uploads with cURL. This is the default and you need to provide the filename of the file(s) you would like to stream in form of strings.

```
// URL on which we have to post data
$url = "http://localhost/tutorials/post_action.php";
// Any other field you might want to catch
$post_data['name'] = "khan";
// File you want to upload/post
$post_data['file'] = "@c:/logs.log";

// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();
// Set URL on which you want to post the Form and/or data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Data+Files to be posted
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
// Pass TRUE or 1 if you want to wait for and catch the response against the request made
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// For Debug mode; shows up any error encountered during the operation
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
// Execute the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Just for debug: to see response
echo $response;
```

Apart from that default method, it is *not* possible to use cURL to stream upload a file using the POST method.

Answer (score 0):

Command to upload a binary file

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/hello/read' \
-H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
--data-binary '@/Users/krishna/Documents/demo.bin'
```

command to upload a text file

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/hello/read' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-binary '@/Users/krishna/Documents/demo.txt'
```

Set the Content-Type as per the file content.