# PHP upload file from server to another server using curl post

Tags: php, post, curl, upload

I need some help please.

I have a php script which generates a xml file and then i need to submit this to another server using POST. The XML file is ok as i can manually upload it using curl from the command line.

my code is:

```
$file = 'temp.xml';
file_put_contents($file, $output);
$post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=>'@'.$file);
$url = "<URL>";
$chlead = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chlead, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "<USER>:<PASSWORD>");
curl_setopt($chlead, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($chlead, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($chlead, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($chlead, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($chlead, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($chlead, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
$response = curl_exec($chlead);
```

I can manually upload the file to the server which handles is correctly by:

```
curl -v -k -u <USER>:<PASSWORD> -X POST --upload-file temp.xml <URL>
```

What am i missing? I am using PHP 5.2.17. Also if there is a way of doing this without writing the xml file to disk that would be good to know.

Thanks

Comment: You need to submit it like a form with the headers. Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085990/post-a-file-string-using-curl-in-php

Comment: Thanks Brian! I had to add the code:     `curl_setopt($chlead, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($output))); `

Answer (score 0):

check the target and the file  url path is correct or use the absolute path