# PHP image Upload to Remote Server

Tags: php

I want to save image to this `'http://198.164.241.108/~bss/api/images/upload_images';`location

I tried the following

```
$url = 'http://198.164.241.108/~bss/api/images/upload_images';

$img = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Using Curl

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '`http://198.164.241.108/~bss/api/images/upload_images`');

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But both of these not working

Comment: Of course it will not work - you need to emulate the form submission. The best way to achieve it - with help of cURL functions. Analyze the data sent from the form and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085990/post-a-file-string-using-curl-in-php

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, it's remote server, so you have to make connection to that server and use [`ftp_put()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php). Also, to use `$_FILES` global variable, you need to use some HTML form first (i hope you just skipped this obvious part in your question).