# How to programatically HTTP POST a CSV file directly from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, csv, post, curl, fputcsv

I'm contributing data to the opencellid.org website. They have several API options to submit data but the only bulk method requires an HTTP POST file upload with the API key as a POST field. Formats acceptable are CSV, JSON and CLF3. I store the data in an SQL database for internal use and periodically submit data to opencellid.

At the moment the script that I use to submit the data to opencellid queries the SQL DB for the most recent measurements and then saves it as a CSV file on the server and then immediately uploads it via HTTP POST. In my eyes this is inelegant.

So my question is, can you POST upload a CSV file directly from an array without first having to actually create a CSV file on the server?

Here's the code snippet we currently use.

```
//Create and save CSV
$output = fopen("opencellid.csv","w") or die();
fputcsv($output, array_keys($celldata[0]));

foreach($celldata as $cell) {
    fputcsv($output, $cell);
}   

fclose($output) or die();

//Upload CSV
$target_url = 'http://opencellid.org/measure/uploadCsv';

$file_name_with_full_path = realpath('./opencellid.csv');

$post = array('key' => 'opencellidapikey',
              'datafile'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path.";type=text/plain");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$postresult = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Can anyone suggest a way to directly upload a CSV from an array?

Comment: Your script converts the array in to a csv file and posts it. I'm not sure that you can get much simpler than that. You need to create the csv data somehow otherwise how would you submit it?

Comment: I was thinking there may be two conceptual ways, first is to create a string that contains the CSV and echo it. The second would be to pass some sort of filepointer reference in to fputcsv which would pass in to curl or file_get_contents...

What I'm doing now works fine. But I'm OCD like that so asked the question.

Comment: Ah i see. You might be able to use a combination of fputcsv to php://output + output buffering to capture the data to a variable. Then post that variable. I will be able to write a full answer later on if noone else has.

Comment: if they accept json as input, it would be easier to just get the data from the db as an array and call json_encode($row)

Comment: Yes they do accept JSON but the "weird" thing is they expect it as an uploaded file so the same problem arises. As I'm uploading some 120,000 rows a day I prefer CSV as it is more data dense than JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to capture the csv data in to a variable using fputcsv to php://output with output buffering.  Since the service only allows multipart format for the submission, you need to construct the payload like this.

```
<?php

//Construct your csv data
$celldata = array(
    array(
        "heading1",
        "heading2",
        "heading3",
    ),
    array(
        1,
        2,
        3,
    ),
    array(
        4,
        5,
        6,
    )
);

//Output to php://output
ob_start();
$outstream = fopen("php://output", 'w');
foreach($celldata as $cell) {
    fputcsv($outstream, $cell);
}   
fclose($outstream) or die();
$csv_data = ob_get_clean();

$url = 'http://opencellid.org/measure/uploadCsv';
// Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085990/post-a-file-string-using-curl-in-php

// form field separator
$delimiter = '-------------' . uniqid();
// file upload fields: name => array(type=>'mime/type',content=>'raw data')
$fileFields = array(
    'datafile' => array(
        'type' => 'text/plain',
        'content' => $csv_data,
    ),
);
// all other fields (not file upload): name => value
$postFields = array(
    'key'   => 'opencellidapikey', //Put your api key here
);

$data = '';

// populate normal fields first (simpler)
foreach ($postFields as $name => $content) {
    $data .= "--" . $delimiter . "\r\n";
    $data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . $name . '"';
    $data .= "\r\n\r\n";
    $data .= $content;
    $data .= "\r\n";
}
// populate file fields
foreach ($fileFields as $name => $file) {
    $data .= "--" . $delimiter . "\r\n";
    $data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . $name . '";' .
             ' filename="' . $name . '"' . "\r\n";
    $data .= 'Content-Type: ' . $file['type'] . "\r\n";
    $data .= "\r\n";
    $data .= $file['content'] . "\r\n";
}
$data .= "--" . $delimiter . "--\r\n";

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $delimiter,
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)));  
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec($handle);
var_dump($result);
```

I get API key error, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks. Let me have a try of this. I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Intreesting question. The only thing I can think of is that you echo the "csv data" with headers of a post and that it's a csv file. That should not create a file on the server afaik. Not sure fully how to approach it, but if you run set apache headers or whichever server system you're using. Give it a shot and let me know if it works.

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing. It's somewhat involved but they could create a `.htaccess` file that redirects "requests" for `opencellid.csv` to something like `opencellid.php` which simply parses the databases, sets the headers, and echoes the content.

Comment: The way curl is used at the moment requires a filename & path. If it used a filepointer there may be a way to do it. The only other way I can think of is the using file_get_contents to do the HTTP POST and create the CSV as a string. I had a quick look at how it could be done but the code seemed "messy" such as having to manually define mime multi-part boundaries etc.

Will keep on trying.