# PHP: Can I cURL POST a base64 encoded string as a file to an API

Tags: php, curl, base64, http-post

I'm trying to move a file from one API (call it "API-A") and cURL POST it to another API (call it "API-B").

API-A gives me the file as a base64 encoded string.

Right now, I can convert the string, save it as a file, post it, then delete it on my end.

This works, but it feels inefficient. Is there any to take the base64 string I got from API-A, convert it to a blob or something, then POST it as a file?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST a file string using cURL in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085990/post-a-file-string-using-curl-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the question was already answered here:

[POST a file string using cURL in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085990/post-a-file-string-using-curl-in-php)

I got hung up on the file-encoding portion. Good catch by Bytewave.